# required selector for select2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

i want set background color yellow for select2. If I set for input just like this it's working

```js
$('#dllSelect').select({
  allowClear: true,
  placeholder: ""
})
```

```css
input:required {
  background-color: yellow;
}

select:required {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select type="text" name="dllSelect" id="dllSelect" class="form-control" required>
  <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
</select>
```

But went using select it's not working. How to set it? **Note:** https://select2.org/

Comment: Fixed the formatting. The select is `yellow` ...

Comment: I dont really know what you're asking because I dont see any problem on the code.

Comment: @Akrion : He/She is using select2 library so default css  won't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one approach to set background colors to only specific selects (to the `required` ones in your case)

Usage of the option `containerCssClass` ([docs](https://select2.org/configuration/options-api))

```js
$(".select2").select2({
 containerCssClass: function(e) { 
   return $(e).attr('required') ? 'required' : '';
 }
});
```

```css
.select2-selection.required {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<form>
    required select2 #1: <select class="select2" required  name="test">
    <option>Test</option>
    <option>Test2</option>
</select>
    <br/>
    NOT required select2 #2: <select class="select2"  name="test1">
    <option>Test</option>
    <option>Test2</option>
</select>
<br/>
</form>
```

**Relevant code changes:**

```
$(".select2").select2({
   containerCssClass: function(e) { 
     return $(e).attr('required') ? 'required' : '';
   }
});
```

With this, an **additional** class will be applied to the `select2` container to which we can apply custom CSS.

```
.select2-selection.required {
   background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

In this case, only the first select will have a yellow background as it has a `required` attribute.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i found just like this `select:required + span .select2-selection{ background-color: yellow !important; }`

Comment: Sure. That'd work as well although I'd prefer having a customClass giving out more flexibility to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do something like this :

```
.select2-results ul li {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Check the demo here :
http://jsfiddle.net/5f0r9vsy/

Comment: I want color not in option. color like in snippet

Comment: thank. please check http://jsfiddle.net/5f0r9vsy/6 . I'm just want color in required